# What software and Speakers are these in this picture?

Tags: software, live, speakers

Could anyone help me? I would like to know what software/Interfaces and what speaker (the ones with the yellow ring) in this pic.

[image: This is the pic]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you by any chance have a higher resolution photo?

Comment: Sorry.. I have no high res version of the pic. :(

Comment: that's ok, I got bored enough to go on a scavenger hunt through B&H for the items I didn't know.

Comment: @JeffersonSantos - do you mind my asking why you need to know, or is it just a curiosity thing.  There are other cheaper options that will behave similarly if you are actually looking for something that works like that, though all live gear is fairly expensive (>$1000).

Comment: @AJHenderson I had actually thought that the "multicam screen" was an app. In reality i'm looking for an app for osx that can simulate that behavior: take multiple video inputs in realtime and output only one for live streams and so on.. I've tried Boinxtv and wirecast.. both interesting, but none with an interface close to this image. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: for live, Microsoft's Expression Encoder Pro will do the job fairly well for WMV based streams.  (It also supports cutting in pre-rendered video clips and overlays.)  For others who may be looking for something for an offline NLE, Adobe Premiere Pro has a fairly nice multicam editing mode for pre-recorded files.

Comment: Err, whops, apparently MS stopped selling Expression Encoder Pro and switched to a cloud based only option... (that makes no sense).  I'm not sure what would be good now then.  The Expression Encoder [page](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/) does have some third party tools listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell the exact speaker model, but they are studio monitors from [KRK Systems](http://www.krksys.com/krk-studio-monitor-speakers.html).  The devices on the bottom of that photo are production switchers, which are designed for doing live video production.  The screens appear to be the monitors for the switchers themselves, so it isn't software, it is hardware.  You are also probably looking at atleast 25 grand worth of equipment there.

I can identify the surface on the right as a [Panasonic AG-HMX100](http://www.panasonic.com/business/provideo/AG-HMX100.asp), which lists for about 6 grand, because I've used that particular model before, but the other's I'd need higher resolution to identify.  The left one is a [NewTek TriCaster 460](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=1021605&is=REG&Q=&A=details).  That is also what you are seeing the screen for, at least on the left monitor, if not also the right.  The full kit for that is around 20 grand between switching hardware (not visible in the photo) and control surface.